# Unable to pass props between classes using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.3/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/0.14.3/react-dom.min.js"></script>

class carSelection extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <Button> {this.props.name} </Button>
        );
    }
}


class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            currentPage: 'Your Car',
            carSelected: null
        };
    }




    renderCarsList() {
        //const carNames = ['porsche', 'Ford', 'Subaru'];
        const carName = "Porsche";
        return (
            
            //{carNames.map((carName) => <carSelection name = {carName} />)} was inside div
            <div>
                <carSelection name = {carName} />
            </div>
        );
    }



    render() {
        const menuItems = [
            "Your Car"
        ];

        return (
            <Grid centered celled padded>
                <Grid.Row>
                    <Grid.Column width={2}>
                        {menuItems.map(item => (<Button fluid>{item} </Button>))}
                    </Grid.Column>
                    <Grid.Column width={10}>
                        {this.renderCarsList()}
                    </Grid.Column>
                </Grid.Row>
          </Grid>
          );
    }
}

export default App;
```

I am trying to pass a prop from `renderCarsList()` to `carSelection`. Like this it builds but does not display any buttons. I have been trying to do it the same way as the **react tic tac toe tutorial**. I also tried with `carSelection` as a function but no luck.

I have not been able to do anything with this `form:<carSelection name = {carName} />`. When it was a function it worked using `carSlection()` but I cannot pass props like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write `CarSelection` with capital `C`. Lower-case names are considered to be HTML tags.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use camel-case naming in your class name. Try to use pascal naming instead.

eg: `CarSelection`

Answer (score 0):

Your carSelection component should capitalize the first letter。React will recognize the component with Capital lowercase to be native html element.